# Devise Authentication for users from Multiple GApps Domains

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise, omniauth

I have a rails app with Devise 1.4.9. Currently, it allows only users from mydomain.com to use the application. I need to open it up to some contractors that work for me. Their domain is theirdomain.com.

How do I expand this line [from the OmniAuth guide](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/OmniAuth%3a-Overview) to allow users from two domains?

```
config.omniauth :google_apps, :store => OpenID::Store::Filesystem.new('/tmp'), :domain => 'mydomain.com'
```

Include 'theirdomain.com' as well.

And also, how do I write a test for it? I've already written spec tests with sign_in_user "test", but they pass even without "test@mydomain.com". I don't have an account on their domain so cannot test easily.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't seem like it'll work. I did a deep dive into the gem code and it only supports one domain.

I'm going to switch to open id instead.